# Method works on emulator but crashes on device. Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to create a method that will return the amount of time that has passed since a request was made. This method takes in one parameter called `requestTime`. Since the time can be in both 24hr ex: `"08/25/16, 14:34"` or 12hr ex: `"08/25/16, 2:34 PM"` the method takes into account all these variables and handles them properly. Now here is the problem: this method works on Playgound, and on the emulator, but not when I run it on my device. (See pictures below)

```
func calculateTimeSinceRequestWasMade(requestTime:String) -> String{

//Empty variable for 24 hour format
var dateIn24HrFormat = ""

if(requestTime.containsString("AM") || requestTime.containsString("PM")){

    //If request time was in 12 hr format we convert it into 24hr
    let dateFormatter1 = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, h:mm a"
    let date = dateFormatter1.dateFromString(requestTime)
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, HH:mm"
    dateIn24HrFormat = dateFormatter1.stringFromDate(date!)

}else{
    //If it was already 24hr we just assign it to our 24hr variable
    dateIn24HrFormat = requestTime
}


//Create a time object of the current date in the desired format
let today = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, HH:mm"
let currentFormattedTime = formatter.stringFromDate(today)

//Create a formatter
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, HH:mm"
let dateAsString = dateIn24HrFormat

//Assign both variable with nice names
let postTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString)
let currentTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(currentFormattedTime)


//Compare the time of both posts and the results is divided by 60, so the result is in minutes
let timeSincePost = (currentTime!.timeIntervalSinceDate(postTime!)/60)

if(timeSincePost < 60){
    return ("\(Int(timeSincePost))m")
}else{
    return ("\(Int(timeSincePost/60))h")
}

}
```

As you can see, in this playground file the method works for both 24hr and 12hr formats. Both method calls returned "6h" meaning that the post was made 6 hours ago.
[image: Screenshot 1: Playgrounds]

HOWEVER, **whenever I run this method on my device it simply doesn't work.** It crashes as it forcefully unwraps an nil. If I run this on the built in emulator, it works, but whenever I run it in my actual device it doesn't.
[image: Screenshot 2: Running on device]

This is the weirdest bug that I have encountered... The Device that I'm running this in is an iPhone 5s running 9.0.2. Please help me if you can!

Comment: Where are you getting `reqeustTime`? When it comes to actual devices, localization can often cause some issues with date/time operations.

Comment: I'm getting the request time from a server and localization shouldn't be a problem in this case.

Comment: That's as far as you know..

Comment: What is the region format in your phone and your simulator? To get region format goto : Settings -> General -> Language & Region

Comment: Region format is exactly the same in the simulator and the physical device. `Language: English`, `Region: United States`, `Calendar: Gregorian`.